# How to enable both HTTP and HTTPS for AJAX-enabled WCF service?

Tags: ajax, wcf, https

Here is my config settings, which currently only allows HTTP:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyAjaxSvc">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MyAjaxSvcEndpointBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="MyAjaxSvc" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyAjaxSvcEndpointBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

This service could potentially be called on any page on my website. Some pages are HTTPS, so I would like to set it up so that the service can be called (AJAX) using either protocol. Ideally, I would like all my AJAX service calls to be HTTPS, but since you can't mix protocols, I will settle for allowing the service to be called using what ever protocol the current page is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shot in the dark:

You'll need to add another Binding (declared above the code you show (normally)), and then declare another endpoint.

Comment: Excellent. I set the security mode of my 2nd binding to 'transport', and it all worked. Thanks!